# TypeError while using pydbgen module

Tags: python, faker

I'm trying to use some functions from pydbgen module. Some of them work while the others keep getting me the following error:

```
import pydbgen
from pydbgen import pydbgen
myDB=pydbgen.pydb()

testdf=myDB.gen_dataframe(5,['name','city','phone','date'])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/BIrainSensor.py", line 5, in <module>
    testdf=myDB.gen_dataframe(5,['name','city','phone','date'])
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pydbgen\pydbgen.py", line 330, in gen_dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=self.gen_data_series(num,data_type=fields[0]),columns=[fields[0]])
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pydbgen\pydbgen.py", line 191, in gen_data_series
    fake.seed(self.seed)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\faker\proxy.py", line 83, in __getattribute__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Calling `.seed()` on instances is deprecated. Use the class method `Faker.seed()` instead.
```

I tried to google it but found nothing.
I also tried to downgrade Faker to version 2.0.0 but it doesn't work

> UPDATE: It seems that the code works fine in CMD prompt but it still doesn't work in Pycharm

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible that `gen_dataframe` receives only stringed arguments. So try changing  5 to '5'

Comment: @redmicelles it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [Faker 2.0.5](https://pypi.org/project/Faker/2.0.5/) worked for me

```
pip install Faker==2.0.5
```

**Example:**

```
myDB = pydbgen.pydb()
testdf = myDB.gen_dataframe(5,['name','city','phone','date'])
print(testdf)
```

**Output:**

```
               name            city  phone-number        date
0      Ronald Reyes  South Oroville  631-367-2892  1984-04-14
1      Scott Nguyen       Glenmoore  350-506-1497  1978-11-18
2     Joseph Rogers     Cherry Tree  315-937-6733  2012-11-13
3  Alisha Whitehead            Iola  870-884-0471  1998-02-04
4  Christopher Cook       Liverpool  370-595-5729  2017-10-30
```

Comment: That's pretty weird. I installed Faker 2.0.5  but it still doesn't work

Comment: are using ide or jupyter?

Comment: I'm using Pycharm

Comment: I tried to run the code in CMD prompt. It gave me an error that says that (openpyxl) moudle is missing so I installed it and managed to make it work in CMD prompt but it still doesn't work in Pycharm. Do you have any idea how can I make it work in Pycharm as well?

Comment: @AhmedA I dont' know why it's not working for you in pycharm. I am able to get the output when i use faker 2.0.5

Comment: Nevermind. Your first solution made it. I was just installing Faker 2.0.5 by using pip. This time I had to install it from Pycharm itslef. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.
I check the link https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/fakerclass.html. and based on the upgrade guide in above link to change the pydbgen.py file. Then the problem  fixed.
Here is what i did:
based on the upgrade guide in above link, we need redefine Faker as below:

change from:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
fake.seed(0)# This will raise a TypeError
```

to

```
from faker.factory import Factory
Faker = Factory.create
fake = Faker()
fake.seed(0)
```

In pydbgen.py.

let's locate the line 8 of the file. and change the import and define statements in function **init** to as below

```
 def __init__(self,seed=None):
     """
    Initiates the class and creates a Faker() object for later data generation by other methods
    seed: User can set a seed parameter to generate deterministic, non-random output
    """
    from faker.factory import Factory #this is line 8,change to import from Factory
    import pandas as pd
    from random import randint,choice
    Faker = Factory.create  #add this line to define Faker= Factory.create
    self.fake=Faker()
```

then restart the python console, and retry the command, problem solved

hope this helps